# image upload to AWS S3 using nestjs and typescript

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nestjs, bucket, aws-sdk-js

I want to upload images to AWS S3 bucket from nestjs using multer-s3.
This is how i have wrote my code to configure with AWS S3:

```
import * as multer from 'multer';<br>
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';<br>
import * as multerS3 from 'multer-s3';<br>

const AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME = process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME;<br>
const s3 = new AWS.S3();<br> 
AWS.config.update({<br>
accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,<br>
secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,<br>
});

@ApiBearerAuth()
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
@Post('/:hotelid')<br>
@UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
@UseInterceptors(
  FilesInterceptor('file',5,{
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME,
    acl: 'public-read',
    key: function(request, file, cb) {
      cb(null, `${Date.now().toString()} - ${file.originalname}`);
    },
  }),
  fileFilter: imageFileFilter,
}),
)

    createRoom(
    @Req() req:any,
    @Param('hotelid') id:number,
    @UploadedFiles() file,
    @Body() createRoomDto : CreateRoomDto,
):Promise<Room>
{   
    return this.roomsService.createRoom(req.user,createRoomDto,id,req.files);  
}
```

This code worked fine but I want to use AWS-SDK-JS-V3.
In aws sdk-js-V3, I can't use AWS.config.update({....})

Can you please suggest me how can I change my code from aws-sdk-js v2 to aws-sdk-js-v3?

Comment: Do you know for a fact that multer will actually work with SDK v3?

Comment: I am not sure about it.